# SQL Row Combination

Tags: sql, select, row, combinations

My table has

```
SNO   VA
1      A
2      A
3      A
4      A
11     B
12     B
21     C
22     C
```

VAL has 3 possible values here. It could be any number upto 17 and the below output can have 17 values joines together.
Example here is with 3 values

And I need my output as

```
1,11,21
1,12,21
1,11,22
1,12,22

2,11,21
2,12,21
2,11,22
2,12,22

3,11,21
3,12,21
3,11,22
3,12,22

4,11,21
4,12,21
4,11,22
4,12,22
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a cross join on the same table thrice:

```
SELECT     a.sno, b.sno, c.sno
FROM       mytable a
CROSS JOIN mytable b
CROSS JOIN mytable c
ON         a.val = 'A' AND b.val = 'B' AND c.val = 'C'
```